# How to merge foreign table columns in a row | TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I want to merge the columns on the foreign table to the row that I am fetching. The Relationship is One-to-One. I want to have a `getMany()` return data that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "MenuID": "1",
        "MenuName": "testmenu",
        "PageName": "testpage"
    }
]
```

Not this:

```
[
    {
        "MenuID": "1",
        "MenuName": "testmenu",
        "Page": {
            "PageName": "testpage"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: It's a bit weird. I think your tables relation is @oneToMany,  because you mentioned Pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could use `.getRawMany()` and use `.select(["Page.PageName as PageName"])` to get what I needed